# Proc Summary is Cutting Data

Tags: sas, summary

I am using a proc summary statement to group my data, but it is cutting off any data with a servicemonth value less than 201601. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I have tried switching servicemonth to a numeric field, and it does the same thing. Here is my code:

```
proc summary data = Group nway; 
    var Day All Scr Adj ICB DFB Qty AP GCA GCB LRO NP PP IS LIC_AMT LIC_Adj
    Sales B_Amt Gap_Amt RPT_Amt Pay_Amt TOTAL_COST TOTAL_AMT ;
    class product Status ind Form B_G_S ServiceMonth Phase; 
    output out = output.Group_T01 sum=; 
quit;
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 2):

If you add `missing` to the proc statement, or the class statement, I suspect it will fix the issue you're seeing.  Most likely one of the class variables is missing for servicemonth values less than 201601.

By default, `PROC SUMMARY` (and most `class`-based procs) exclude observations missing values for any of the `class` variables.

Comment: You are right! This is what is happening. Thank you!